# Call system to paste file together

Tags: ruby

```
file = ["file1","file2",...].join(" ")

`paste "#{file}"`
```

Hello, I have this simple problem that has been bugging me for days. I want to use Ruby to select files to paste together, but when I use the above code, it returns saying that files are not found. If I run for a single file, e.g. `paste file1`, it works. Does someone see why the code isn't working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "paste together"? Join or concatenate the filenames into a single string?

Comment: Hi, what I mean is actually to join the files together, side-by-side.

Comment: The problem isn't pasting things together. You can do that in many different ways. The problem is in the way the filename is constructed that is passed on to `paste` in this case (see my answer below). But this piece of code fails just as hard with `ls` or any other external command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you quote #{file}. The thing that is executed is `paste "file1 file2"`.

You probably want `paste #{file}` which would result in `paste file1 file2`. In your case, paste expects a file that is called "file1 file2" (filename with a space).

In other words, remove the double quotes in your second line.

Comment: AH. thank you very much. I got it now. I didn't know you don't need to put "" to get text extrapolation in ``.

Comment: By the way backticks work just as double quotes. You an use string interpolation `#{...}` in the same way, so you don't need to add extra double quotes.